# c++ dynamic_cast of template argument type variable

Tags: c++, templates, dynamic-cast

Why does dynamic casting not work on a vector which specialized by  template parameter type?

How can I solve this problem? I would like to determine from a vector whether the elements in it are descendants of a specific class?

```
class A {};
class B : public A {};

template<class _T_> void func(std::vector<_T_> &vect )
{
    A* pA = dynamic_cast<A*>( vect.data() );
    if( pA != nullptr) { /* I'm happy!*/ }
    else  { /* I'm sad! */   }
}

void main()
{
    std::vector<B> vectorOfB;
    func<B>( vectorOfB );
}
```

Comment: That works fine here (once I added the missing `#include` and corrected the signature of `main()`).  What error do you get?

Comment: Your identifier `_T_` is dangerous, as it's reserved for use by the implementation _for any purpose_ (including macros).

Comment: Note that though with the proposed syntax change by @TobySpeight your code compiles, but the `dynamic_cast` remains dangerous depending on what you intend to do in the "I'm happy"-block: I am assuming in the real world `A` and `B` are not empty. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/5PGYqxqnz

Comment: Yes that is right. This is just a simplified example to illustrate the problem. Neither the classes nor the vector are empty.

Comment: Side note: `void main` is not a valid signature for `main`. It *always* returns `int` - `int main`.

Comment: Yes, you are right and I know that. It's just an error that doesn't touch the point right now.
It should be said that I haven't had to manually write a single main function for decades... it's always generated with the new project.

Comment: Also note that even when `pA` points to a single `A`, it doesn't point to an  array of `A`s . The vector elements are still `B`s.

Comment: Doesn't `std::is_base_of<A, T>` or `std::is_convertible<T*, A*>` (or other type_traits) do the job?

Comment: It looks strange that you're using `dynamic_cast` to the _base_ class - did you have that the wrong way around?  `dynamic_cast` is more normally used to determine whether a `A*` points to a `B` - all `B*` point to some kind of `A`.  And `A` doesn't have any base classes, so the template can't be instantiated with any type that can be down-cast to it.

Comment: @Jarod42, that's a compile-time test, but perhaps that's what Viktor is looking for.  Question lacks sufficient clarity.

Comment: @TobySpeight: There are no pointers involved here, we have `T` and `A`. So decision can be made compile time.

Comment: Oh yes - it's a vector of objects, not of references (or of `std::reference_wrapper`s).  So it should be a compile-time test - agreed.

Comment: Also keep in mind that if you do any sort of type conversion on a pointer to the first element of an array or vector then you can no longer use the converted pointer to traverse the array, since doing so would use the wrong size to find the next element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for the answers!
They were very helpful.

It was really a mistake to search for the base class with dynaic_cast.

I found the answer to my problem in Jarod42's post:
"Doesn't std::is_base_of<A, T> or std::is_convertible<T*, A*> (or other type_traits) do the job? – Jarod42 Sep 15 at 12:07"

Answer (score 4):

The `vector` is empty so it *must* fail. Compare with this:

```cpp
B* bp = nullptr;
A* ap = dynamic_cast<A*>(bp);
std::cout << ap << '\n';       // <- 0
```

Add an element:

```cpp
std::vector<B> vectorOfB(1);
```

And then check the element:

```cpp
template <class T>
void func(std::vector<T>& vect) {
    if(vect.empty()) return; //     Can't check non-existing elements

    A* pA = dynamic_cast<A*>(&vect.front()); // or vect.data()

    if (pA) { /* I'm happy!*/
        std::cout << "happy\n";
    } else { /* I'm sad! */
        std::cout << "sad\n";
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rahsPsjrT)

Comment: In the live code, I also check the size of the vector...
The problem is with the template parameter. I get a compile-time error:
MSVC compiler :  error: C2681: '_Ty *': invalid expression type for dynamic_cast

Comment: @Viktor If you copy the demo and compile it with MSVC, doesn't that work? It compiles clean in MSVC in Compiler Explorer.

Comment: I tried it and of course your solution works with MSVC. I made another mistake. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I've had to do something similar before, and the way I've done it might not be optimal, but it did work.

The first thing is to make the function take a vector of *pointers*, rather than a vector of the object type itself (I recommend using C++ "smart" pointers for this). So the signature would be something like:

```
void func(std::vector< std::unique_ptr<A> > &vect )
```

When you're actually constructing the vector in the main function, you can then do something like this:

```
std::vector< std::unique_ptr<A> > vectorOfB; // Nope, not a typo! 
vectorOfB.push_back(std::make_unique<B>());
func(vectorOfB);
```

So the next part of this is how do you tell within "func" whether each element is an A or a B. The way I did it was by declaring a virtual function in the parent class like this:

```
class A
{
    virtual bool isB() const { return false; }
};
class B : public A
{
    virtual bool isB() const { return true; }
};
```

Admittedly this might not scale well, because if you had lots of classes instead of just two you'd have to have a lot of these functions, but it works.

So now inside "func" you can loop through the vector, and for each index i you can call "vect[i]->isB()" to get a boolean to tell you whether it's an A or a B. If that's all you need to do then you're done, but it's possible that you might want to call some function that the class B has but that class A doesn't. In that case, the following *won't* work:

```
if (vect[i]->isB()) {
    vect[i]->someFunctionSpecifictoB();
}
```

Instead you have to cast it first:

```
if (vect[i]->isB()) {
    static_cast<B *>(vect[i].get())->someFunctionSpecificToB();
}
```

Hopefully that's all you need!